# Can I see how I have affected other users' reputation?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, statistics

Can I see how I have affected other users' reputation? That is, I would like to know how much reputation I have caused certain other users to gain.

It would be even more interesting to rank other users with respect to the reputation changes which I have caused them.

And, would this be a useful feature to have? More statistics is always interesting.

Comment: Besides some novelty value, what would the interest of knowing that be?

Comment: @Bart The present answer below has good points. I think that it is a question of balancing "interesting" against "dangerous".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has multiple parts so I'll answer just this one: Can I see how I have affected other users' reputation?

There are three interpretations of this:

- Is that information available to you at all?
- Is that information available to you in a convenient format, on your profile?
- Can you run a query, on https://data.stackexchange.com/, to get the information you want?

## Is that information available to you at all?

Well, trivially, yes. You can figure this out manually with a *lot* of effort: if you go to the Votes section on your profile you can see all the votes that you cast. You can click into each, manually filter out all those except the target user, jot down upvote vs. downvote into a spreadsheet, and then run a formula that multiplies the number of downvotes by -2, and, since our recent change of question/answer equality, multiply upvotes by 10.

Of course you *may* be able to automate your actions here via a Selenium script but it would be clunky and brittle i.e. not robust against future SE changes to UI elements.

## Is that information available to you in a Convenient Format?

That is, is the information available at a glance from some sort of dashboard on your profile? Well, the existing answer of Madara's Ghost seems to suggest that it's not. But that's 7 years old at the time I'm posting this. So I'm not going to offer a definitive answer in this regard, but I'd imagine this is still the case. Perhaps somebody can comment to clarify.

## Can you Run a Query to Get the Information you Want?

No. Upvotes/downvotes are not exposed in the data explorer for an obvious reason: it would ruin the anonymity of them! (Thanks commenter)

Comment: VoteTypeId 5 is not an upvote. It is favorite (or now known as bookmark). We do not expose upvotes and downvotes in the Data Explorer.

Comment: Ah crap I thought it would have been a bit weird to do so. I'll update the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Interesting? Sure. Useful? Not so.

Reputation is a rough measurement of a user's expertise and community trust level. Like a veteran-o-meter if you'd like.

While it would be considered "fun" to have that feature, does it have a real function? Will it (or should it) affect your decisions (since the information would obviously only be visible to you) regarding the user in question? Would it make you vote for him less or more? I'd like to think not.

Voting is about the *content*, I very rarely even look at who posted an answer or a question when I vote, be it positively or negatively.